# Regex - How to match something without a specific prefix?

Tags: regex

I have the following pattern:

```
[a-z]{1,2}-\d{1,2}
```

And it must matches these situations:

```
A-1
B-1
```

And ignore these:

```
A-1-1-1
A-1-1
```

So, ignore when the suffix is `-`.

Comment: What do you mean by "ignore"? Should it match and ignore the rest, or should it not accept?

Comment: What programming language or text editor are you using? Different regex engines have different constructs and features.

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes `\b` matches `-`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either use anchors (if the strings are separate) or a look-ahead:

```
^[a-z]{1,2}-\d{1,2}$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/tM4nU0/1)

The version with look-ahead:

```
\b[a-z]{1,2}-\d{1,2}(?!-)\b
```

Another [demo](https://regex101.com/r/tM4nU0/2)

**Note** the use of the `i` modifier, otherwise `[a-z]` won't match uppercase letters. It can also be added as a `(?i)` inline option: `(?i)\b[a-z]{1,2}-\d{1,2}(?!-)\b` in most regex flavors.

Comment: Note that without the second `\b` you will get matches like `az-12` given the `az-123456` as input.

Answer (score 1):

You can use lookahead:

```
\b[A-Za-z]{1,2}-\d{1,2}(?!-)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lK3lT3/1)

If these are the only strings per line then you can use anchor `^` and `$` also:

```
^[A-Za-z]{1,2}-\d{1,2}$
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regexp already match what you want, just add case-insensitive (i - option) and anchor.

```
/[a-z]{1,2}-\d{1,2}$/i
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question then it seems ok to just anchor the regex in the end with a $

```
(?im)[a-z]{1,2}-\d{1,2}$
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this

```js
^[a-z]{1,2}-\d{1,2}$
```